# How to use STR_TO_DATE with INSERT INTO in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, csv

What i want to do is to import a CSV file in my database. The first column, named `mydate`, of the CSV file contains the date in this format `m.d.Y H:i:s`. I'm trying to insert the file from a form in php. Here is the code:

```
if(isset($_POST["Import"])){

    $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0){

        $file = fopen($filename, "r");
        while (($getData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE){

            $conn=getdb();

            $sql = "INSERT into pay (Mydata,ID,Transaction,ReceiptNo,ServiceID,) 
                     values (STR_TO_DATE(Mydata, '%m.%d.%Y %H:%i:%s'),'".$getData[1]."','".$getData[2]."','".$getData[3]."','".$getData[4]."')";
```

It imports data in all the columns except the first one. I cant understand what I'm doing wrong. I have seen a lot of examples with `STR_TO_DATE` and `INSERT INTO` and i think that the way that i'm writing it, is correct. But still doesn't work.

Comment: `STR_TO_DATE(Mydata, '%m.%d.%Y %H:%i:%s')`? i think you have to give a date string insted of `Mydata` there

Comment: convert it php and pass the variable in the query. Tried that?

Comment: @AlivetoDie In some tutorials i find that i can put the name of the column there. And it works if i use it in mysql workbench

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo how can i convert it php?

Comment: `STR_TO_DATE(NOW(), '%m.%d.%Y %H:%i:%s')` use it and check

Comment: @AlivetoDie I replaced `Mydata` with `NOW()` but it still doesn't return values for the first column

Comment: @irena can you tell me what setting you have on the `Mydata` column in your database?  Is it DateTime or VARCHAR or something else?  It only seems logical to me to save it as 'Y-m-d h:i:s'.  What is your plan?  I'll submit a new answer when you answer my question.

Comment: @irena How many iterations is your while loop going to do?  Is it always only one iteration?  or more?  It would be most useful if you would do a table EXPORT on your database and post that with your question.

Comment: @mickmackusa i solved it by using `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` it upload's the data much faster. I will update now the question with the code

Comment: @mickmackusa just updated. I can't save it in that format because there are a lot of data and i cant go and change the format for every file that i'have to upload. For the export I m using something else.

Comment: @irena The overal quality of your question would be dramatically improved if you could show your database table's structure (post the EXPORT so we can see the column types) as well as a sample $_FILES input file (obfuscate the data if necessary).  This would show all of the relevant components of your scenario.  If you do this, please ping me and I'll come back and upvote your question for being complete and informative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using [LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html).

Here is the code that I used:

```
if(isset($_POST["Import"])){        
    $filename=str_replace("\\", "/", $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0){                 
        $conn=getdb();               
        $sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$filename."'
                INTO TABLE pay
                FIELDS OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' TERMINATED BY ','
                LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'
                (@Mydata,ID,Transaction,ReceiptNo,ServiceID)
                SET Mydata = STR_TO_DATE( @Mydata, '%m.%d.%Y %H:%i:%s')";
    }
}
```

Comment: Well done, but the bulk of your solution and its explanation belongs here in your answer, not the question.  Please remove your question update and deliver your informative solution here in the answer.  Thank you for working to self-solve and provide an answer to the community -- that's excellent SO citizenship.

Comment: @mickmackusa i just removed the update and put the solution in the answer. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I've edited your answer to provide a link for your `LOAD DATA INFILE` statement.  Are there any helpful tips that you have or snags that you had to work out when implementing this solution?  These types of additions can save a future SO researcher heaps of time and heartache.  If you have more functions that belong inside of these nested condition blocks, it may help future readers to see your full querying process including error checking and affected_rows checking.  A comprehensive answer provides the best education and will earn you more upvotes in the long term.

Comment: p.s. Where did the while loop go?  I was curious if you were making successive INSERT queries, because if so, it would have been better to build up one massive big, long INSERT with multiple rows of values and then only query once.  Please show more code so I can see how this works.

Comment: @mickmackusa I'm making only one INSERT Query because I only have to insert data once a day in a given format.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way

```
$sql = "INSERT into pay (Mydata,ID,Transaction,ReceiptNo,ServiceID,) 
 values (date('m/d/Y H:i:s', strtotime(MyData)),'".$getData[1]."','".$getData[2]."','".$getData[3]."','".$getData[4]."')";
```

Comment: I put the strtotime like this `values (date('m.d.Y H:i:s', strtotime(Mydata)),'".$getData[1]."','".$getData[2]."','".$getData[3]."','".$getData[4]."')` now it show me this error:  **Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' strtotime(Mydata))**

Comment: Mydata should be a variable that holds the value of the cell in you csv.
$Mydata = 'CSVcellThatHoldsTheDate';
Then use date(date('m/d/Y H:i:s', strtotime($MyData))

Comment: Something like that: $Mydata1=$getData[0]; ?

Comment: I now changed my code like this: `$dataime1=$getData[0]; .....values (date('m.d.Y H:i:s', strtotime($Mydata1)),'".$getData[1]."','".$getData[2]."','".$g‌​etData[3]."','".$get‌​Data[4]."')` but it still send me to an error like this **Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' strtotime(04.13.2017 23:59)),'1...**